# Is there any Ubuntu Certification?

Tags: canonical

I am a Windows Server Administrator and MCSE/MCTIP. I have been attracted towards UBUNTU for long time and want to become a active participent and help businesses to use and grow using Ubuntu. But I do not have much of technical knowledge in Ubuntu/Debian. So I am seeking technical course that will certify me as Ubuntu Server Engineer and as a consultant I would be able to suggest businesses to implement Ubuntu Server and Cloud infrastructure.

I have gone though: [Ubuntu Certification Announced;](http://www.ubuntu.com/news/ubuntucert) but not sure how to obtain that course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can begin with Linux Professional Institute Certification Level 1 and then Level 2.

One can the study material ***[HERE](https://www.lpi.org/study-resources/teaching-linux/)***

Hope that will help !!

Answer (score 4):

The announcement is rather old (April 4, 2006) and to my knowledge, such a programme does not exist nowadays.

There are however the certifications of the [Linux Professional Institute](http://www.lpi.org/).